# Как в linux сделать клавиши цифрового блока в режиме ввода цифр эквивалентными стрелкам?

Tags: ubuntu, клавиатура

У меня на клавиатуре сломались клавиши со стрелками вверх и вправо поэтому я использую клавиши цифрового блока без Num Lock. В windows они вели себя практически также как и стрелки, но в linux есть отличия. Например, нажимая 4(переместить курсов влево) курсов перемещается, но если зажать shift для выделения, то просто напечатает 4, а не выделит символ перед курсором. В pycharm эти клавиши вообще не дают никакой реакции. Могу ли я в ubuntu ubuntu 16.04(gnome) как-нибудь на уровне системы приравнять клавиши перемещения на цифровом блоке к стрелкам, чтобы можно было, например, выделять текст shift+6 на цифровом блоке?

Comment: может вам поможет https://askubuntu.com/questions/57079/xubuntu-make-shiftnumpad-work-like-windows

Comment: DeKaNszn, CIIacu6o. TeIIepb 9 mogy Bbl6upaTb tekcT kak B windows, Ho pyccka9 packJlaDka IIepecTaJla PaboTaTb. Takshe pycharm Bce ecIIIe He peagupuet Ha kJlaBuIIIu

Comment: Перезагрузка исправила проблему с раскладкой. Проблема с клавишами в pycharm решилась изменением настроек в самой программе